# Users added via graph not receiving welcome email

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

First I tried adding a group owner as both owner and member in the same http call as I created the group:

```
{
  "description": "test group",
  "displayName": "test_group",
  "groupTypes": [
    "Unified"
  ],
  "mailEnabled": true,
  "mailNickname": "project.1-TestPreview",
  "members@odata.bind": [
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}"
  ],
  "owners@odata.bind": [
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}"
  ],
  "securityEnabled": false,
  "visibility": "private"
}
```

The user is added as a member and owner successfully, but not receiving a welcome email.

I then tried to split the http calls, thinking that there was an issue with the emails as the group was created at the same time as the user was added.

I created the group with one user being added in the creation http call same as above and three other users being added as owner and member ~30 seconds after the group was created. For this I used

queries:

```
{
  "type": "POST",
  "url": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch"
}
```

body

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "body": {
        "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}"
      },
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      "id": "1",
      "method": "POST",
      "url": "groups/{id}/members/$ref"
    },
    {
      "body": {
        "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}"
      },
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      "id": "2",
      "method": "POST",
      "url": "groups/{id}/members/$ref"
    },
    {
      "body": {
        "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}"
      },
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      "id": "3",
      "method": "POST",
      "url": "groups/{id}/members/$ref"
    }
  ]
}
```

I added the users as owners with the same method. None of them received a welcome email. How can I make sure that the email fires?

I am doing this in Logic Apps:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

You need a proper Microsoft 365, Office 365 or Exchange license. Do you have one?